# How to add packages installed manually to the system's package database?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center, eclipse, qt

I installed QT Creator by off-line installer in Ubuntu 14.04 and now i want to install Ubuntu SDK but it still lists QT Creator as software that need to be installed in the system.
Ubuntu Software Center also lists QT Creator as Non-Installed software .
What to do , the same problem is with Eclipse , Netbeans and other softwares also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `apt-mark`. For example if you want to mark `qtcreator` as manually installed :

```
sudo apt-mark manual qtcreator
```

You can check which packages are (marked as) automatically installed :

```
apt-mark showauto
```

and which packages are (marked as) marked as manually installed:

```
apt-mark showmanual
```

Check `man apt-mark` to get more idea.